# node-cron tasks terminated after restart the server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, scheduled-tasks, node-cron

The project in which I am working completely dependent on cronjobs functionality like firebase push notification 1 day before the subscription expires. the problem is when I restart the server all cron jobs are terminated.  how can I solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Agenda.js & Agendash .
Npm install agenda agendash
Agenda save your jobs in database & triggered even you reboot your server . Agendash give you a dashboard for monitor or test your schedule jobs

Answer (score 1):

Save your cronjobs to database, and use only values in database or defaults?